# how to design microservices with less network hops

Tags: microservices

We have a couple of microservices A and B, each is an independent module with its own code and its own database, C* and Oracle.

Service B has multiple tables - T1, T2, T3.

For each POST request in Service A, it has to contact Service B to get some meta information from table T1 only. Since, service A is in a critical path and has a very heavy traffic, getting information from Service B for every single POST call is going to be a bottle neck.

I was thinking of 2 options:

1. Caching data hosted in Service B on Service A, so the information can be fetched from a cache as it will be faster - the strong consistency is another other business requirement and there is a risk that we might use stale data from the cache.
2. Moving the information in T1 completely to Service A so it doesn't have to make a network hop - the problem with this approach is Service B has transactional boundaries during data creation that will affect T1, T2, T3 so all the data in Service B should stay together.

Is there a better way to design this kind of a high consistency system still being able to scale?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: You say "Since, service A is in a critical path and has a very heavy traffic, getting information from Service B for every single POST call is going to be a bottle neck."   That smells fishy.  Microservice architectures generally involve microservices calling each other so the network latency should not be a problem.  Why can't you just add more instances of Service B until it can handle the load?  If it's the DB that can't handle the load, then maybe service B can use memcache to help with that.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - Thanks for the response. That is how the current architecture is and we noticed some performance issues around it. Just for this one REST path, I am trying to remove Service B from the critical path to improve the performance. At this point of time, if that has to happen, to keep the system highly consistent, I only see an option to merge both A and B into a Monolith - but I would like to see if there are better options.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use events.

When Service B changes data in table T1, it raises a domain event (publishing a message to a message broker or service bus).

Service A subscribes to that event. When it receives a message, it updates its local copy of table T1. It's not the system of record, but it will always be up to date (within the latency of the broker/bus and the time to process the message queue). Then when service A needs data, it serves it up from its local T1.

For more detail on this and other techniques, see [Managing Data in Microservices](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/microservices-data-centric) by Randy Shoup, particularly the section on Microservice Techniques: Shared Data.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So basically you have suggested #2 option and keeping the data updated. Since high consistency is also the business requirement, do you think updating the local copy is better compared to contacting Service B directly to keep itself up-to-date - both in terms of consistency and latency ?

Comment: @DevDev Well, you said calling B on every POST would be a bottleneck. If you don't - if you cache the data - you lose out on consistency. In any case your mileage may vary; you'd need to measure and compare the results against your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i will measure it out.